# Merge two sheets on two columns into a new sheet in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

I'm using Excel 2011 on OSX. I have Sheet1 that looks like this:

```
pupil_id    date            test_score
1           2015/10/01      98
2           2015/10/01      83
```

And I have Sheet2 that looks like this:

```
pupil_id    date            test_score
1           2015/10/01      69
2           2015/10/01      97
```

I want to create a third sheet that looks like this:

```
pupil_id    date            test_score1     test_score2
1           2015/10/01      98              69            
2           2015/10/01      83              97
```

Surely this must be easy, but I can't figure out how to do it, despite much Googling.

I've tried using Consolidate, and I can figure out how to add the two ranges, but I can't figure out where to specify the fields that I want to merge on (`pupil_id` and `date`). Also, I'm confused by the way that Consolidate seems to want you to choose an aggregate function.

[image]

Anyway, I've tried using the Consolidate options above, but when I click "OK" nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Are the same Pupils on both sheet 1 and 2? And are the dates the same? If each Pupil is listed only once on each sheet, and the date is the same for that pupil on each sheet, then You could copy the first column from one of those sheets to sheet 3 and then us vlookup formula. So in cell b2 of sheet 3 you would use the formula =VLOOKUP(A2,SHEET1!$A$2:$C$##,2,FALSE). This would copy the date for that pupil. This formula is saying:

1. Lookup the value I have on sheet 3 in cell A2
2. Find it on Sheet 1 in a table that goes from A2 to C## (replace the ## with how many rows sheet 1 goes to)
3. After finding that value, return what is in column 2 from Sheet 1
4. FALSE tells it to find an exact match only.

You'll want to make sure you use the $ in the table definition ($A$2:$C$3), otherwise when you copy this formula down your sheet 3 each new row will alter the table range.

You would use the same formula in cell c2 on sheet 3, but you would tell it to return column 3. This would get their test score from sheet 1. Then use the same formula in cell d2 on sheet 3, but tell it to pull from sheet 2 and return column 3. This would get you their test score from sheet 2.

Once you have all formulas in b2, c2, and d2 you can copy them down to the bottom of the sheet.

I also recommend, once you have your final result, selecting all, copy, and "paste values". This will remove the formulas, but keep the data. Unless, of course, the scores might change on sheets 1 or 2 and you want them to automatically update on sheet 3, then you would leave the formulas in place.